# Detect the circle and measure pixels

Tags: image-processing, grayscale, edge-detection, hough-transform, threshold

[image]

In this image I need to detect the vehicle rims and measure the pixel length of the rims via image processing. I think I should follow the circular Hough Transform for circles. can you guys please advice me which steps to follow to acquire the width of the rims?  ex(gray scale->edge detection, or any other comment on this )

Comment: Hough transform is a good option for this task. Before that, you need to tranform your image in gray levels and perform a edge detection. But what is your question? How to do those operations?

Comment: My advice on which steps you should follow: 1) Google/Wikipedia color to grayscale conversion. 2) Google/Wikipedia edge detection.  3) Google/Wikipedia Hough Circle Transform.  4) Actually **try** to perform steps 1-3 in code, by yourself.  5) Come back here and ask a concrete question -- currently, it sounds like you just want someone to do your hard work for you.

Comment: thanx for the answer, yeah you kind of right! i will eork on my skills . thank you again.

Answer (score 7):

Here is how I would do this in Mathematica:

[image]

Here you have a direct measurement, off by 1 Pixel.

[image]

**Edit**

### Here you have it applied to your other question

Question: [what are my research areas for image processing project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611591/what-are-my-research-areas-for-image-processing-project)

[image]

Comment: @Ross Thanks! In fact this method works only for very homogeneous backgrounds. The general case is much more difficult.